# Equivalent to in_category() for subcategories

Tags: categories

Wordpress provides conditionals like is_home() and is_category(). I'd like a function to tell me if the current context belongs to a category that is a subcategory (so, not a parent).

I tried this, but it returns true on any category (and subcategory) context

```
function is_subcategory($category) {
    if (is_category()) {
        foreach ($category as $c) {
            if ($c->parent > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
function is_subcategory($category = null) {
    if (is_category()) {
        if (null != $category){
            $cat = get_category($category);
        }else{
            $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
        }
        if ($cat->parent == 0 ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
//to check if the current context is a subcagetory:

if (is_subcategory()){
    //its a subcategory;
}else{
    //nope is aparent category
}

//to check if a specific category is a subcategory pass its ID, eg:
if (is_subcategory(12)){
    //yes category with the id of 12 is a subcategory;
}else{
    //nope is aparent category
}
```